# Create custom page with NSIS

Tags: installation, nsis

I'd like to create a custom page using nsis. Just text, at different heights and possibly some image. Something similar to what oracle does:

[image]

From the [docs at "Custom Pages"](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Docs/Modern%20UI%202/Readme.html) this is the way a custom page should be created:

```
;--------------------------------
;Pages

Function CustomPageFunction
  !insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT "TITLE" "SUBTITLE"
FunctionEnd

  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
  Page custom CustomPageFunction
```

I am looking for additional guidlines on how to create very basic custom installer pages, because unfortunately, no new page with "TITLE" and "SUBTITLE" is displayed after MUI_PAGE_WELCOME as if extra instructions need to be added. What am I missing?ž

UPDATE for setting image:

```
var Image
var ImageHandle

Function CustomPageFunction
; !insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT "TITLE" "SUBTITLE"

nsDialogs::Create 1044
Pop $0

${NSD_CreateBitmap} 0 0 100% 100% ""
Pop $Image
${NSD_SetImage} $Image "C:\Users\User\Desktop\TrickyWays\test.png" $ImageHandle

${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 40% "Hello, welcome to nsDialogs!"
Pop $0


nsDialogs::Show
${NSD_FreeImage} $ImageHandle
FunctionEnd
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation you linked to only talks about custom pages in relation to the MUI header text. There is a ... there in the function where you are supposed to put the actual custom page code. I will try to fix that part of the documentation.

A custom page requires a plug-in and the most popular one is probably [nsDialogs](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Docs/nsDialogs/Readme.html). A custom page that does not call a plug-in is automatically skipped.

```
!include nsDialogs.nsh
!include mui2.nsh

Function myPageCreate
!insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT "TITLE" "SUBTITLE"

nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0
${If} $0 == error
    Abort
${EndIf}

${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 12u "Hello, welcome to nsDialogs!"
Pop $0

${NSD_CreateText} 0 13u 100% -13u "Type something here..."
Pop $0

nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
Page custom myPageCreate 
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English
```

Comment: Aaah.. Thank you for taking your time.  I've searched the page at link for "size", "font" and "bold" to perform some styling on the label, but there are no instructions on how to do that. I also tried to place an image using NSD_CreateBitmat and NSD_SetImage. The image does not show up. I pasted the function code Sorry for the dumb questions :) I truly find the the docs terrible.

Comment: For the font, look at CreateFont and SetCtlColors in the main help-file. For the image, you have two problems: 1) You can't use a path like that, you need to extract to $pluginsdir (the nsDialogs readme has a example). 2) You must use a .BMP, Windows has poor .PNG support in these controls.

Comment: There is also user friendly visual tool for creating nsDialogs: https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Install_Designer (for people who do not know the scripting/programming syntax etc.)